# NestJS Inject module service inside in a non module file

Tags: javascript, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs, inversifyjs

I have a function file for view render and i want to use nestjs modules service in here. My render file is like this.

```
export default {
  parse() { }
  render() { }
}
```

So to use module service in here i tried to inject like this.

```
import { Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MemberService } from './member.service';

class SampleClass {
  constructor(@Inject('MemberService') private readonly memberService: MemberService) {}
}

// Creating class in here to use in functions
const sampleService = new SampleClass();

export default {
  parse() { }
  render() { }
}
```

When i try to create new class in here i got error "Expected 1 arguments but got 0"

My MemberService is like this

```
@Injectable()
export class MemberService {
  constructor(@Inject(Constants.RelationshipMemberModel) private readonly relationshipMemberModel: typeof Model) {}
  login () {}
}
```

So how should i inject service to use in this file ?

Answer (score 3):

In order to Inject a provider the component has to belong to a **context** (Basically a module) in the nest application, basically it has to be or a **Injectable**, **Controller**, **Async Provider** or a **Custom Async Provider**, and it has to belong to a Module in which it has access to the provider you are trying to inject. In order to use a functionality of a service in external javascript classes that are not in a context you can import the service and you gotta instantiate it by yourself here you can have an example of this aproach:

```
class SampleClass {
  private memberService: MemberService; 
  constructor() {
    this.memberService = new MemberService();
  }
}
```

Remember this is another instance of the service and if you don't take care you will have multiple instances on runtime as it is not an injectable anymore but a class object. In order to prevent this maybe you can create a **singleton** containing all the MemberService functionality and import it in both the MemberService and the SampleClass:

```
export class MemberFunctionality {
  private static memberFunctionality: MemberFunctionality;
  private constructor() {}
  static getInstance(): MemberFunctionality {
    if(!memberFunctionality) {
      this.memberFunctionality = new MemberFunctionality();
    }
    return this.memberFunctionality;
  }
  login() {}
}
```

Then you import it on both MemberService and SampleClass and call the getInstance method

```
import { MemberFunctionality } from './member-functionality.ts';

class SampleClass {
  private memberFunctionality: MemberFunctionality;
  constructor() {
    this.memberFunctionality = MemberFunctionality.getInstance();
  }
  ...
}
```

same goes for the MemberService

```
import { MemberFunctionality } from './member-functionality.ts';

@Injectable()
export class MemberService {
  private memberFunctionality: MemberFunctionality;
  constructor(@Inject(Constants.RelationshipMemberModel) private readonly relationshipMemberModel: typeof Model) {
    this.memberFunctionality = MemberFunctionality.getInstance();
  }
  login () {
    return this.memberFunctionality.login();
  }
}
```

And that would take care of only having an instance of that functionality

Answer (score 1):

I did it 2 different way

1. In your module, listen to `OnApplicationBootstrap` and inject it manually yourself

   ```
    import { Module, OnApplicationBootstrap } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { ModuleRef } from '@nestjs/core';
    import { SampleClass } from 'src/commons/SampleClass';
    import { MemberService } from 'src/module/MemberService';

    export class YourAwesomeModule implements OnApplicationBootstrap {
      constructor(private moduleRef: ModuleRef) {}
      onApplicationBootstrap() {
          // implement singleton here
        const sampleClass = SampleClass.getInstance();
        const memberService = this.moduleRef.get(MemberService);
        sampleClass.setMemberService(memberService);
      }
    }
   ```

Actually you can just pass `this` into SampleClass from the constructor of MemberService if decouple is not required.

2. For a similar case (pass instance between different module), I use the UseGuard, add instance to request object from another module and use it in Controller/Service class.